# How to use integration by parts

Tags: integration, proof-verification, partial-differential-equations

Let $K:\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ defined by  $K(x,t)= (4\pi t)^{-n/2} e^{-|x|^2/4t} \ (t>0)$ and $K(x,t)=0$ if $t\leq 0.$
And $\phi\in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R)$ (smooth functions with compact support).  Fix $\epsilon>0.$

> How to use integration by part to show  conclude that:
>
> $$\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty} \int_{\mathbb R^n} K(x,t)\,[(-\partial_{t}- \Delta)\,\phi(x,t)] \,dx\, dt = \int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}\int_{\mathbb R^n} [(\partial_{t} -\Delta)\,K(x,t)]\,\phi(x,t)\, dx \,dt + \int_{\mathbb R^n} K(x,\epsilon)\, \phi(x, \epsilon) \,dx$$

Edit: This step has been used the Folland's Intro to PDE book p. 146 in Theorem 4.6. Theorem states that $K$ is a fundamental solution for the heat equation.

Edit: it is known that $\int_{\mathbb R^n} |K(x,t)|\,dx=1$ for all $t>0$.

Comment: You have tagged this `proof verification`. Can you show us your candidate proof, or at least tell us what you have tried so far? :)

Comment: @SamT: Thanks. I have edited the question. The book just says that by elementary integration by parts it follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following hint should hopefully be of help.

Observe that when you integrate by parts, you get
$$ -\int_\epsilon^\infty K(x,t) \partial_t \phi(x,t) dt
= - \Big[ K(x,t) \phi(x,t) \Big]_\epsilon^\infty + \int_\epsilon^\infty \partial_t K(x,t) \phi(x,t) dt. $$
Note that $K(x,t)\phi(x,t) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$ for every fixed $x$. This sorts out the 'time' part.

I leave it to you to do the 'space' part. Note that the Laplacian is 'like' a second derivative. Thus we'll need to do integration by parts *twice*, and in particular we *won't* get a change of sign (unlike for the time part). You have that $K$ is *compactly supported*; this will (help to) show that the first '$[\cdot]$' term of integration by parts gives no contribution.